# Oracle certification (OCA JP-1z0 803 and OCPJP- 1z0 804)

Tags: java, oracle, ocpjp

As I know, to become an Oracle Certified Professional Java SE 7 Programmer, have to pass both OCAJP and OCPJP exams. And it is possible to do in any order (ex – OCAJP --> OCPJP or OCPJP --> OCAJP).

Yesterday I was able to pass OCPJP exam and I am hoping to sit for OCAJP this month.

My Question is, does Oracle provide me a hard copy certificate for OCPJP exam (1z0 804)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Oracle site says that you can complete the steps in any order, but you must complete all prerequisite steps to achieve certification at the current level.

So you can take OCPJP exam, then OCAJP exam, but you won't be certified in either until the OCAJP exam is complete, since OCAJP is prerequisite for OCPJP certification.

Once you have met the prerequisites, you can request a hard copy if you prefer that to downloading it.

If you just passed OCPJP, OCAJP should be a piece of cake for you, since it's comparatively much easier.. so the only hassle is it's an extra $300 that you must pay Oracle before getting your OCPJP cert.

Once you pass OCAJP, get OCPJP and OCAJP hard copies here.

[Oracle Java Cert Hard Copy Request Form](http://education.oracle.com/pls/web_prod-plq-dad/db_pages.getpage?page_id=616)

Comment: what is about 'the only hassle is it's an extra $300 that...'? OCAJP fee is only $150?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to Oracle FAQ for this [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/certification/entry/0376).

You will receive your certificate approximately 6-8 weeks after passing the certification exam.